# Trying to get a count of labels used in Gmail using Gmail API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail-api

I am trying to go one level deeper with the demo code that utilises labels to extract the count of each label used within my inbox. e.g label1 = 5, label2 =10 etc and with a date. Any suggestions?

Demo code:

```js
function listLabels() {
  var response = Gmail.Users.Labels.list('me');
  if (response.labels.length == 0) {
    Logger.log('No labels found.');
  } else {
    Logger.log('Labels:');
    for (var i = 0; i < response.labels.length; i++) {
      var label = response.labels[i];
      Logger.log('- %s', label.name);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. What is the question? Where did you find the demo? Have you already read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview?

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at using the `Users.messages:list` function call here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list . You could get a list of messages that match a given label Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Users.messages:list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) function call from the [GMail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/) should get you your results.

The trick here is to pass `label.id` to the `labelIds` argument as a list

```
function listLabels() {
  var response = Gmail.Users.Labels.list('me');
  if (response.labels.length == 0) {
    Logger.log('No labels found.');
  } else {
    Logger.log('Labels:');
    for (var i = 0; i < response.labels.length; i++) {
      var label = response.labels[i];

      // Use the label name to get the messages that match this label
      var label_messages = Gmail.Users.Messages.list('me', {'labelIds': [label.id]});

      Logger.log('%s = %s', label.name, label_messages.resultSizeEstimate);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! If you're happy with my answer, if you could mark it as correct that would be great!